# Geocoder getFromLocation(lat,lon) doesn't work

Tags: android, geolocation, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoder

I have an activity which first uses an `AsyncTask` to get and parse data from a server.
The entries contain a latitude and a longitude.

Then, in `onPostExecute()` I load my adapter and display my listView. And in my adapter's `getView()` I try to display the location with the latitude and the longitude :

```
private String getPosition(String longitude, String latitude)
{
    float lon = Float.parseFloat(longitude),
          lat = Float.parseFloat(latitude);

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MyActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try
    {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1); 
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0) return "No location found.";
    else
    {
        String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
        String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
        return (city + ", " + country.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

I always get "No location found." but I'm sure some entries are correct. For example one has  a latitude of 39.017 and a longitude of 125.73. Google's API show there is at least one address for it :

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=39.017,125.73&sensor=true

I've also declared this in my Manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

But all this won't return any address. Any idea why?

Comment: What are you running this code on?

Comment: @Selecsosi On my emulator, may this cause this issue?

Comment: Your location is in North Korea, I'm wondering if that could be the issue. Have you tried hardcoding a location in a major western city?

Comment: The geocoder is notorious for not performing well/at all on some devices (specifically the emulator and genymotion as well as some sony, htc devices). Here is a gist i put up that is an example of an AsyncTask I use to load locations, it firsts tries to use the geocoder and if not, falls back to making a request to the google maps api, https://gist.github.com/selecsosi/6705630. This task is using Volley to make a blocking request in the task but if you use something else, RoboSpice, etc... should be easy to modify

Comment: @NathanZ No it's not, I tried it also with Paris or New York and same problem occurs.

Comment: @Selecsosi Thanks for this interesting information. I will have a look at this.

Answer (score -1):

geoCoder.getFromLocation (Reverse Geocoding) method will work when you build avd (virtual device) target as Google API 19 and also the application is built with the target set as "Google API 19" (you can modify the build target using Project->Properties). This worked for me. Should you need more details please reply to this post.